# how to use firebase.database().transaction() method efficiently in expo react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I am trying to get the orderid that I have stored on the Realtime Database of Firebase. For getting the data I have been using the `firebase.database().transaction()` method to avoid use conflicts between realtime use.

All I am trying to do is that get the id to assign it to the current order, then increment it by +1, and then return it to the firebase again. But the problem is that whenever I try to assign that value through the transaction method, I get a null or undefined object.

It does increment the value stored on firebase, but doesn't give an appropriate value to assign to the order object.

So, what can I do to get this done more efficiently?

here's the code I have been using to get the job done:

```
await firebase.database().ref().child("Order_Id").transaction((value) = > {
  //Sending data to firebase to book the order 
  firebaseRef.child(value).set({
    Appliance_Name: item.title,
    Service_Requested: orderData.serviceType,
    Image: orderData.uploadedImage,
    User_Problem: orderData.problem,
    Location: orderData.latitude + " , " + orderData.longitude,
    Status: "Booked",
    Time: dateTime,
    Assign: ""
  });
  return value + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to write to two different nodes of your RTDB in a transaction mode: `firebase.database().ref().child("Order_Id")` and `firebaseRef.child(value)`.

Therefore the transaction needs to apply **on a common ancestor of these two nodes**. As explained in the doc, the update function (i.e. `(value) = > {}` in your case) needs to takes the current state of the data (`value`) as an argument and returns the new desired state you would like to write.", i.e. the new value of the data tree for this common ancestor node.

Comment: Could you please explain along with code.... ??